# cant call variable in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJjd5.png)I want to make a simple call to layout resources I already have in Android app as below. All I need to do is to be able to use a variable such as myInteger (having values such as 1,2,3) and call R.layot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hassan brother hello from Turkey.Change your code with this ok?

```
class AnmailAdapter(val context: Context, val listOfAnmail: ArrayList<Anmail> ): BaseAdapter() {

override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {

    val anmail = listOfAnmail[p0]

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity, p2, false)
    val tvName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
    val tvDesc = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDes)
    val imgView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imgView)

    tvName.text = anmail.name
    tvDesc.text = anmail.des
    imgView.setImageResource(anmail.image!!)

    return view
}

override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
    return listOfAnmail[p0]
}

override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
    return p0.toLong()
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return listOfAnmail.size
}
}
```

If your kotlin version lower than me ;

```
val tvName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
```

instead;

```
val tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName) as TextView
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **Build>Rebuild Project** or **Build>Clean Project** in your android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `(myView.findViewById(R.id....) as TextView).text = animal.name!!`

Or if you using `kotlin-android-extensions` check imports in this class. If you have view with duplicated id from different layout imported you can't use extentions as well